# How to use .Include() in EF Core with ViewModel

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first, ef-core-3.1, ef-core-3.0

I have two models

```
public class PageGroup
{
    public PageGroup()
    {
        Pages = new HashSet<Page>();
    }

    public int GroupID { get; set; }
    public string GroupTitle { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Page> Pages { get; set; }
}

public class Page
{
    public Page()
    {
        
    }

    public int PageID { get; set; }
    public int GroupID { get; set; }
    public string PageTitle { get; set; }
    public string PageText { get; set; }
    public virtual PageGroup PageGroup { get; set; }
}
```

and a ViewModel

```
public class ShowGroupsViewModel
{
    public int GroupID { get; set; }
    public string GroupTitle { get; set; }
    public int PageCount { get; set; }
}
```

I filled this ViewModel with this method

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<ShowGroupsViewModel>> GetListGroupsServiceAsync()
    {
        return await _context.PageGroups.Include(p => p.Pages.Count).Select(pa => new ShowGroupsViewModel()
        {
            GroupID = pa.GroupID,
            GroupTitle = pa.GroupTitle,
            PageCount = pa.Pages.Count
        }).ToListAsync();
    }
```

but **PageCount** is not work. when run the project is has zero value. How can I fill this property?
I use .net core 3.1

Comment: I don't think `Include` can be used for this scenario because actually you don't fetch the included data at all, the `Count` is translatable to the sql query. try selecting without `Include` and set `PageCount = pa.Pages.Count()` - Note about using `Count()` instead of `Count`. I'm not so sure if the LINQ is smart enough to translate that into the correct sql query. If it's not working, you may have to explicitly join & group to get the desired result (should be possible).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using Ef 3.1 Include should not be used because Include("Pages") will bring all Page instances from the SQl server and count them after this.

In EF Net5 it would be done much more simple, using Include, but since you are using EF 3.1 try this:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<ShowGroupsViewModel>> GetListGroupsServiceAsync()
    {
    return await ( from pg in  _context.PageGroups
           join p in context.Pages
           on pg.GroupId equals p.GroupId 
           group pg by new { pg.GroupId, pg.GroupTitle}  into g
            select new ShowGroupsViewModel{
             GroupId = g.Key.GroupId,
             GroupTitle =g.Key.GroupTitle
             PagesCount = g.Count()
          }).ToListAsync();
    }
```